# ubiquiti unifi controller cant log in

Tags: router

I had a ubiquiti wap. I went to reset it and couldn't. I couldn't log in. So, I hard reset it. Unifi-discover showed it in "default" state. That was good. But, when I brought up the controller it kept asking me for a username and pass and wouldn't accept the default.

So, I sent it back as defective. They sent me a brand-spanking-new WAP (upgraded model even).

Plug it in. Unifi-discover says it's in default state. I open the controller and, again, it asks for username/pass.

I have discovered that it talks to a local mongodb but it's all in the same directory. I deleted the app (thus clearing the mongo directory), reinstalled, SAME ISSUE!

How do I recover this thing? I won't send a recovery email. Nothing!

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im3iGa9XxRo&t=59s) of the original problem

Answer (score 0):

Each router comes with a default username and password. If you reset your router, it was simply asking for the defaults. For ubiquiti products, I believe, the default username and password is “ubnt” (ignore the quotations of course). Try this and see if it works

Comment: c'mon now. That's like saying a TV comes with a power switch. I tried all of those. I ended up switching computers and installing unifi. I think some network configuration on my work laptop was interfering.